# Battlefield V icons meaning (up to date source)

Tags: battlefield-v

It seems that all sources for explaining the orange warning icons for Battlefield V are outdated.
Min look different to these

[image]

E.g. i have sometimes an icon showing a stack of frames without '!' all looking the same. I am not sure if this is packet loss or low frame rate or something else.
Sometimes the icons look at least similar to those from Battlefield 4:

[image]

Here i can guess due to similarity. But is there a current source explaining all icons for Battlefield 5?